# Get share links to popup in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to use this popup function:

```
function popupwindow(url, title, w, h) {
  var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
  var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
  return window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
}
```

On these social links:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>" title="Share on Facebook"></a>
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php the_title(); ?>+<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>" title="Share on Twitter"></a>
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>" title="Share on Google Plus"></a>
```

Normally, I'd do something like this:

`<a onclick="popupwindow('http://www.example.com', 'facebook',400,400);" href="javascript:void(0);">Share on Facebook</a>`

But I understand that PHP cannot be used within Javascript because one's server side and one's client side. So how can I make these links pop up?

Comment: You can use php to generate that last clip of code you have. You just can't place PHP in a .js file.

Comment: @mschuett Ok, I see. I just tried using `<a onclick="popupwindow('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>', 'facebook',400,400);" href="javascript:void(0);">.</a>` but when I click on the link, nothing happens. Is there something wrong in the code?

Comment: i believe you have to place echo in front of bloginfo('url') for it to output.. ill check the function though in a sec. hmm no you don't need to do that. What does the console show is output on the page by this code?

Comment: @mschuett Ok, I did that. And I checked the source to confirm and the URL indeed gets outputted correctly. However, when I click on the link, still nothing happens.

Comment: If you put a console.log in your popupwindow function is it being called? just to see if the issue may actually be inside the js function

Comment: @mschuett I just added the console log and it appears the function isn't being called. It says `Uncaught ReferenceError: popupwindow is not defined / onclick`I'm not sure why. I put the function in the JS file with all of my other JS and simply called it. Any ideas?

Comment: add that function in a script tag on the actual page to test it out. If it works then your just going to have to see what is going wrong in your .js file.

Comment: I just tried it and it works on the actual page between the script tags. Weird. Edit: Never mind, it was because it was in between `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: I added in an answer so if anyone else runs across this they know to look into the comments to see what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code should actually work and you can place php in with your javascript function just fine just as you did with your a tags in the second example.

If you read through the comments the issue was actually caused by a JavaScript error.